# Is $GL(\mathcal{H})/\mathbb{C}^* \cong U(\mathcal{H})/U(1)$?

Tags: group-theory, hilbert-spaces

Assume that $GL(\mathcal{H})$ is the group of invertible linear transformations of Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $U(\mathcal{H})$ is the group of unitary operators on $\mathcal{H}$. We know that $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $U(1)$ act respectively on $GL(\mathcal{H})$ and $U(\mathcal{H})$.

Is $GL(\mathcal{H})/\mathbb{C}^* \cong U(\mathcal{H})/U(1)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $U(1)$?

Comment: @ThusleGadelankz I mean $U(1)=\{ e^{i\theta} \; |\; \theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$, the group of unit complex numbers.

Comment: What examples did you work out? For instance, did you analyze the case of 2-dimensional Hilbert space? Also, what kind of an isomorphism do you mean when you write $\cong$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you very much for the comment. By $\cong$ I mean the group isomorphism.  I have'nt worked on any special example yet but I'll try the case of 2-dimensional one. Thank you.